# SSIS Control Flow Expression Logic Flow Limitations?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Running SQL Server 2008 R2/BIDS 2008.

I have an SSIS package that needs to do some branching based on expressions.

When I run in debug, only the 'verify' step (green) runs. After that, even though 1 of the 3 conditions will always exist (expressions are shown in annotations), it just stops.  Why does this happen?  I don't get any errors when creating the flow.

How do I fix this so it actually works?

PS no idea why there is so much white space under the image...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that on the right side of your image is a big object that has two precedence constraints pointing to it.

If those constraints are defined with a "Logical AND" (the default), then both of them must be true for the object to begin processing.

With this structure, if the upper right expression is true when you execute your package, the rest of the package will never execute, because the big object on the right is waiting for both of its incoming precedents to be fulfilled.

If you set the incoming constraints to a "Logical OR", then the object will begin processing as soon as either of the two incoming precedents is fulfilled.

Comment: The "big object" is a Sequence Container, judging by the icon.